# Powershell webrequest not downloading file correctly

Tags: powershell, boost, zip

With recent migration of boost, some of our scripts broke. One of them was responsible for downloading the zip file. Here is the link for the file itself

**https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/native/main/release/1.69.0/source**

File I am interested in is, "boost_1_69_0.zip". The one with size 156.8Mb.

I use the following command to download the file

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/native/main/release/1.69.0/source/1.69.0.zip" -OutFile "C:\pwrShell\1.69.0.zip"`

However, the downloaded file is only 15kb, and not a valid zip. Wondering what I am missing?

Comment: The actual download link for that file would be `https://boostorg.jfrog.io/native/main/release/1.69.0/source/boost_1_69_0.zip` however that doesn't work either as it will give a 404 error. I guess you would need to inspect the traffic when downloading as it seem there is a load balancer behind.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the link. I was trying .70 to see if I can download that.

Comment: This works using the API. I've used Chrome to debug what happens when clinking on the link. But the regular link use the `HEAD` HTTP method, and return a 200 OK instead of a redirect.
`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=main&path=release%252F1.69.0%252Fsource%252Fboost_1_69_0.zip" -OutFile "C:\Data\Tmp\1.69.0.zip"`

Comment: @Hazrelle please post that as an answer so that I can accept. It works! You are awesome. Can you tell me how did you figure that link out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is a bit tricksy - the `boost_1_69_0.zip` link on `https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/native/main/release/1.69.0/source` might look like it links to a zip file but when you click it you actually run some javascript that takes the browser to a web page - `/ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=main&path=release%252F1.69.0%252Fsource%252Fboost_1_69_0.zip`.

This page gives a "302 Found" response that takes the browser to the actual download link at https://jfrog-prod-usw2-shared-oregon-main.s3.amazonaws.com/aol-boostorg/filestore/07/074cb678b05fd327be1096b39a962aeb249372ac?x-jf-traceId=2593752ec87a6551&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22boost_1_69_0.zip%22&response-content-type=application%2Fzip&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211019T222020Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Credential=AKIASG3IHPL63WBBRCUD%2F20211019%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=8e8b21c8a319e8cdc96044b8794dd3a359e265753bb7cf4913999fa753ffb47d

You can see all of this happen if you run a dev proxy like Fiddler in the background while you interact with the browser:

[image]

- Request #3 is my browser loading the index page (including 200+ javascript bundle files).
- Request #252 is when I clicked the `boost_1_69_0.zip` link, which triggered a HEAD request and a GET request to `/ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=main&path=release%252F1.69.0%252Fsource%252Fboost_1_69_0.zip`
- Request #253 is the GET request which receives a 302 Found response redirecting the browser to the actual download link
- Request #256 is the download from the s3.amazon.aws.com site initiated by the browser

So, if you want to replicate what the browser is doing, your best bet is to do something like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=main&path=release%252F1.69.0%252Fsource%252Fboost_1_69_0.zip" -OutFile "1.69.0.zip";
```

`Invoke-WebRequst` will automatically follow the 302 response returned by `https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=main&path=release%252F1.69.0%252Fsource%252Fboost_1_69_0.zip` and will download the file from the url specified in the `Location` header in the response.

**PS**

Your 15kb file that you download from `https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/native/main/release/1.69.0/source/1.69.0.zip` is another web page - try putting the url in your browser and see what happens.

Comment: By the same method, can you tell me what link do you see for boost_1_69_0.zip.json ? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Feel free to download fiddler yourself and find out :-) - https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler. Or look at the "Network" trace in the Chrome dev tools per @Hazrelle's approach.

Answer (score 1):

This works using the API. I've navigated to `https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/native/main/release/1.69.0/source` and used Chrome (F12) to debug what happens when clinking on the link to inspect what happens. But the regular link use the HEAD HTTP method, and return a 200 OK instead of a redirect. `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=main&path=release%252F1.69.0%252Fsource%252Fboost_1_69_0.zip" -OutFile "C:\Data\Tmp\1.69.0.zip"`